# When I use dir([user-defined object]), why does it also return the names in the namespace of the object's parent class?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, namespaces

The dir() function, if no parameters are given, returns the list of names in the current local scope. If we give parameters, however, it returns the names within the attribute namespace of the given object parameter (i.e. attributes of the object). Knowing this, consider the following class:

```
>>> class Foo():

    classVar=23

    def __init__(self,x):
        print("dir in init:",dir())
        self.x=x

    def getx(self):
        return self.x
```

When I call `dir(Foo)`, it returns the list of names defined within the class object Foo (a.k.a list of attributes of Foo) as such:

```
>>> dir(Foo)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'classVar', 'getx']
```

If I do the following:

```
>>> newFoo=Foo(17)
dir in init: ['self', 'x'] #list of names in the local variable namespace from the __init__ method call.
>>> dir(newFoo) #called from the global scope
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'classVar', 'getx', 'x']
```

we can see that list of attributes of `newFoo` (names defined in the attribute namespace of `newFoo`) also include the names defined within its parent class, like `getx`,and `classVar`. I thought maybe `dir()` returned not only the local namespace but the enclosing namespaces as well. I tested this out using a function but it only returned the names within the local namespace and not the enclosing namespace. I was wondering why this is the case with user-defined classes/objects. Why am I also able to see the names within the namespace of the parent class when I cannot access the enclosing namespaces within a function call using `dir()`?

Comment: The calls ``dir()`` and ``dir(obj)`` do entirely different things, on entirely different kinds of namespaces. Note that class and parent-class attributes *are* accessible through the instance – e.g. ``newFoo.getx`` is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace of a class doesn't *enclose* the namespace of its instances. In fact, attribute access on an object `obj.attr` goes through various stages:

1. Check whether a [data descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) named `attr` exists in the [method resolution order](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order) of the object's type: `type(obj).mro()`.
2. Check whether `"attr"` exists in [`obj.__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__).
3. Check whether `attr` exists otherwise in the MRO.
4. Finally, if none of the above was successful and [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) is defined, it will be called with `"attr"` as an argument.

The above steps are handled by [`object.__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) which can be overridden in custom classes.

Also note that a type is free to customize what gets returned by `dir(obj)` by defining [`__dir__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__).

It's also important to note that there is no *class scope* which encloses e.g. the function definition within a class definition (see [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)). That's a common pitfall as can be seen from the following example:

```py
>>> class Test:
...     x = 1
...     y = [i*x for i in range(5)]
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in Test
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Here the list comprehension defines its own scope and tries to resolve the name `x` according to the [LEGB rule](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/) (where "E" stands for "enclosing"). However since the class definition is not a proper scope, it cannot be searched during name resolution.

Comment: If there's no class scope that encloses the methods defined within that class, then how come a method can access the class variables defined within a class?

Comment: @spiritedExit0 How would you access these variables? Typically you do `self.something` and here `something` is resolved according to the rules detailed above (and it may be a class variable). It's not like in Java where you can refer to a method without any object; in Python you need `self` to reference instance/class variables.